# Como usar Z-index pseudo elementos

Tags: html, css3

solo por practicar, quería hacer un botón de hamburguesa solo con Css.
usando un div los pseudoElmentos Before y After.
Ya tengo el 99% de la animación pero por alguna razón no puedo hacer que el after y el before se mantengan detrás del elemento principal.
Este es mi codigo.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after{
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
 display: grid;
 height: 50vh;
 place-content:center;
}
div.cont {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

div.toggle,
div.toggle::after,
div.toggle::before {
  background-color: khaki;
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 2vh;
  width: 6vw;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0 0 0 5px;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.64, -0.53, .14, .99);
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

div.toggle {
  position: relative;
}

div.toggle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: -.5em;
  z-index: -1;
}

div.toggle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: .5em;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: right;
  z-index: -1;
}

div.toggle.check {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

div.toggle.check::after {
  top: -.5em;
  left: -1em;
  transform: scale(0.1, 1);
  z-index: -1;
}

div.toggle.check::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="toggle" onclick="this.classList.toggle('check')">
  </div>
</div>
```

por alguna razón siempre los pseudoelementos se mueven por sobre el elemento principal.

Comment: Cuando te refieres al elemento principal, te refieres a `toggle` verdad ? En este caso el problema es que cada pseudoelemento es tratado como elemento hijo. Es decir el valor `z-index` del elemento principal se suma en cascada.

Comment: exactamente, pero como coloco un elemento hijo detrás de su padre?

Comment: Simplemente no es posible.Tendras que pensar otro modo de como hacer esta animación que por otro lado no me ha quedado del claro. 

Algo que puedes hacer es ocultar el elemento hijo, si al padre le das `overflow: hidden` y un `height` fijo, podrías mover el elemento hijo fuera de la vista (`position: absolute; top: -100%`)

Comment: boomer.
al elemento hijo lo ocultaba dándole un ```transform: scale(1,0)```
Pero quería evitar que elemento se mueva por encima del padre.
voy a dar vuelta la animación para que no se oculten los hijos si no que el padre quede por detrás de los hijos.